# Como resolvo esse código em Python kivy

Tags: python-3.x

Estou tentando programar um calendário usando Python e o módulo `kivy`, porém estou com um problema que não entendo como posso resolver:
Este é o arquivo calendario.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
import calendar
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
cal = calendar.Calendar()

class Gerenciador(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Tarefas(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        for dia in cal.itermonthdays(now.year, now.month):
            self.ids.box.add_widget(Tarefa(text=str(dia)))

class Tarefa(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self,text='',**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ids.label.text = text

class Window(App):
    def build(self):
        return Gerenciador()

Window().run()
```

Este é o Window.kv:

```
<Gerenciador>:
    Tarefas:

<Tarefas>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        ScrollView:
            BoxLayout:
                id:box
                orientation:'vertical'
                size_hint_y:None
                height:self.minimum_height

<Tarefa>:
    size_hint_y:None
    height:200
    Label:
        id:label
        font_size:30
```

Ao executar, ele resulta no erro:

> 'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**'

Apontando para a linha: `self.ids.box.add_widget(Tarefa(text=str(dia)))`.

Answer (score -1):

Olá, olhando seu for para cada dia do mês obtive vários zeros, não testei rodando no kivy, mas tente desta forma para observar se o erro persiste. Abs

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
import calendar
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
cal = calendar.Calendar()

class Gerenciador(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Tarefas(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        dias = [str(dia) for dia in cal.itermonthdays(now.year, now.month) if dia]
        for dia in dias:
            self.ids.box.add_widget(Tarefa(text=dia))

class Tarefa(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self,text=False,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        if text:
            self.ids.label.text = text

class Window(App):
    def build(self):
        return Gerenciador()

Window().run()
```

Answer (score -2):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
import calendar
from datetime import datetime


now = datetime.now()
cal = calendar.Calendar()


class Tarefas(ScrollView):
    def __init__(self,tarefas,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        dias = [str(dia) for dia in cal.itermonthdays(now.year, now.month) if dia]
        for dia in dias:
            self.ids.box.add_widget(Tarefa(text=dia))
            
            
class Tarefa(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self,text=False,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        if text:
            self.ids.label.text = text         

class Window(App):
    def build(self):
        return Tarefas([])
Window().run()
```